# How to exit to prompt in DOSBox?

Tags: cmd.exe, ms-dos, dosbox

For some DOS applications I don't know how to properly quit. I wouldn't mind force quitting.
I would like to return to the original prompt from where I started the DOS application.

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl + C

Comment: Ctrl+Q, Alt+Q, Ctrl+X, Alt+X (Ctrl+Alt+Del)...

Comment: - Workaround using DosBox Keymapper
Press CTRL-F1 to enter the keymapper and select the backslash with your mouse. Press the DELETE button that will show up on your screen. Then press ADD to bind backslash to another key. Simply press an unused key to bind it to this. Press SAVE and then EXIT to return to the main screen.

Comment: That just brings me back to where I was before opening the key mapper. And why do you suggest overwriting the mapping for backslash instead of just opening and exiting the key mapper? For which application does that workaround help? @manjesh23

Comment: It's the programmer, who has control over how to exit the program. If they decided they don't want you to exit the program, then you simply can't (without destroying its "host", which would be the original DOS session in your case). That's also the reason for the different options, cylgalad suggested - and there are more, of course.

Answer (score 2):

All programs/games for DOS may have different key combination to exit to command prompt (command.com itself). Some games and programs will not have any such keyboard combination, they run till reset of the PC/laptop. I am talking about DOSBox here and also DOS directly on computer.

Usually, as cylgalad wrote, the keys may be:

```
Ctrl+Q
Alt+Q
Ctrl+X
Alt+X
Ctrl+C
Esc
Shift+Esc
Alt+Esc
one of F1-F12 keys, and with Ctrl/Alt/Shift modifier
Ctrl+Break (Ctrl+Pause)
and so on...
```

Also there may be option in game's main menu to quit.

`Ctrl+F9` quits from DOSBox.

Answer (score 0):

At anytime in full screen or windowed mode you can terminate the DOSBox application by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> combination.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if your using a batch file to run your programs, but here is my solution. I have a menu batch file to run some games. I have 2 options to exit. If I am done with DOSBox, `exit` shuts it all down. If I want to stay in DOSBox. exit to prompt, a simple `cls` does this.

Here is the short version of my file.

```
:START
CLS
@echo off
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO            ********************************
echo            **** Select from List Below ****
ECHO            ********************************
ECHO            ****                        ****
ECHO            ****   1. PINBALL           ****
ECHO            ****   2. DOOM              ****
ECHO            ****   X. EXIT TO UBUNTU    ****
ECHO            ****   0. DOS PROMPT        ****
ECHO            ****                        ****
ECHO            ********************************
ECHO            ********************************
ECHO.
ECHO.
@ECHO OFF
::choice /C1234567X0 /N
CHOICE /C1234567X0 /N CHOOSE

IF ERRORLEVEL 9 GOTO DOS
if errorlevel 8 goto EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 7 GOTO DESCENT
if errorlevel 6 goto QUAKE
if errorlevel 5 goto DUKE3D
if errorlevel 4 goto ULTIMATE DOOM
if errorlevel 3 GOTO DOOM II
if errorlevel 2 GOTO DOOM
if errorlevel 1 goto PINBALL
:PINBALL
CD EPINBALL
PINBALL.EXE
CD..
GOTO START
:EXIT
EXIT
:DOS
cls
```

Comment: I believe that you’ve misunderstood the point of the question.